# Python Iterating and Comparing Multiple Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of equal length: a and b. List b contains several of the same floating point numbers as list a at the same indices, but the other indices are replaced with zeros. These lists also contain several thousand values each.

I would like to iterate through list b until it gets to a non-zero value then iterate through list a from the same index until a greater value is reached. I want to then append that greater value to an empty list and then continue to iterate through list b until the next non-zero value and repeat.

```
c=[]
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(a):
    if b[i] == 0:
        i = i + 1
    if b[i] > 0:
        j = i
    if a[j] < b[i]:
        j = j + 1
    if a[j] == b[i]:
        j = j + 1
    if a[j] > b[i]:
        c.append(a[j])
        i = i + 1
```

I have tried multiple ways to do this with for and while loops and either end up just appending the whole of list a into the empty list or I create an infinite while loop, so any help or advice on how to get started would be greatly appreciated!

Incorporating @MichaelButscher's answer into this and adding another list d that contains dates that correspond to the values in lists a and b, I then appended the dates for the values that met the condition `if a[j] > b[i]:` into a new list e.

```
d=['05/01/2000','06/01/2000','07/01/2000','10/01/2000','11/01/2000','12/01/2000','23/10/2000','24/10/2000','25/10/2000','13/12/2000','14/12/2000','15/12/2000','20/02/2001','21/02/2001','21/09/2001','19/06/2002','20/06/2002']  
a=[1.86,1.85,1.89,1.82,1.82,1.83,1.846,1.898,1.869,1.923,1.926,1.9677,1.959,2.02,2.802,2.7312,2.8035]  
b=[0,0,1.89,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.9677,0,0,2.802,0,0]

c=[]
e=[]
i = 0
j = 0

# Run until break
while True:
    while i < len(a):
        if b[i] != 0:
            break # break inner while
        i += 1
    else:
        break # break outer while

    # At this point: i < len(a) and b[i] != 0

    j = i
    while j < len(a):
        if a[j] > b[i]:
            # At this point: i < len(a) and b[i] != 0 and j < len(a) and a[j] > b[i]
            c.append(a[j])
            e.append(d[j])
            break
        j += 1

    # At this point either appropriate j was found or j == len(a)
    # Anyway, next i to check

    i += 1
```

lists c and e were then printed in columns:

```
24/10/2000  1.898   
24/10/2000  1.898   
21/02/2001  2.02    
10/09/2001  2.606   
20/06/2002  2.8035  
24/09/2002  3.8132  
22/09/2015  4.0667  
04/09/2015  3.853   
01/09/2015  3.7031  
10/05/2004  3.148
```

Some of the data is repeated and isn't in ascending date order even though the dates in list d were.

Comment: Show what you have done already and what particularly goes wrong.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've updated it with my attempted code that ends up with an infinite while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by nesting while loops. Outer while just runs forever (until break) inner while loops check for desired state.

Untested but should work:

```
c=[]
i = 0
j = 0

# Run until break
while True:
    while i < len(a):
        if b[i] != 0:
            break # break inner while
        i += 1
    else:
        break # break outer while

    # At this point: i < len(a) and b[i] != 0

    j = i
    while j < len(a):
        if a[j] > b[i]:
            # At this point: i < len(a) and b[i] != 0 and j < len(a) and a[j] > b[i]
            c.append(a[j])
            break
        j += 1

    # At this point either appropriate j was found or j == len(a)
    # Anyway, next i to check

    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly! I've just tested it and the a values aren't being appended to c in order for some reason. Also, some values are being duplicated.

Comment: @FreddieLambert Can you create a small test data set showing your problem?

Comment: I've just edited the main question to include my data set.  It also includes the dates that each of my data points was recorded at.

Comment: @FreddieLambert Please show corresponding input for this output.

Comment: I've updated the original question with your code, and the addition that I made to output the date.

Comment: @FreddieLambert But the input data for this output is missing yet. Maybe you can create a reduced version which shows the errors nevertheless if the input is too large.

Comment: I've included a reduced version and it works fine with everything in the correct order, but when I increase the list sizes it goes back to having duplicates and being out of order.

Comment: @FreddieLambert I think the problem is the input data, not the code. Is it e.g. really correctly ordered by date?

Comment: I've double checked and the input is all in the correct order without any duplicates, so something is happening after going through the while loops.

Comment: I actually don't actually think this is a problem because I've gone through the input data and manually done what the code is doing, and it seems the output is fine and just wasn't what I was expecting it to be. However, it seems to be skipping over data when the value of a[j] that is appended to c is the same as one of the non-zero b values.

Comment: @FreddieLambert Item `a[j]` is only added to `c` if it is greater than the reference value `b[i]` as you wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained the problem very well. The problem occurs when a value `a[j]` that is appended to c is coincidentally also one of the non-zero `b` values, so `j` and `i` are the same. This time the item is successfully appended, but when list `b` then iterates to this value later on, it for some reason skips over appending the value of `a[j]` that is greater than this.

Comment: @FreddieLambert I can't see a reason for this. If you could find a small test input that shows that behavior this would help.

Comment: I've looked at it again, and I think that it skipped over the value because there wasn't actually a greater one. Sorry for the confusion and thank you very much for your help!